# numpy.mean of mixing layer height from multiple netcdf files

Tags: python

I know how to calculate the mean of a variable in one netcdf file. But, I have 40 netcdf files. In each file I have 4000 data values for mixing layer height. I want to create a list of mean mixing layer height for the multiple netcdf files. 
In the end the size of my list should be 40.

Can some help me with a python code to create this list? 
Thank you so much.

Here is the code I used to calculate the mean mixing layer height for one layer in a single netcdf file

```
import numpy as np 
import netCDF4

f = netCDF4.Dataset('niv.nc') 


#the shape of my data set is (5760,3)  
#5760 is the number of lists of time   
#In each list I have 3 mixing layer heights for 3 layers.  
#I'm going to call all the mixing layer height data for the first layer 

a= (f.variables['pbl'][:,0])  
print (np.mean(a))
```

Comment: You should look at using `xarray` with `open_mfdataset`. It makes working with netCDF files (especially multiple netCDF files) sooo much easier.

Comment: Oh, also if you want a more detailed answer than that, you should edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get the list of filenames somehow. Here I'll assume you have all your files in one folder, and there are no other netCDF files in that folder.To do this using netCDF4 and requiring a separate mean for each file

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4
from glob import glob

# you want to modify this to use your actual data directory
filename_list = glob('/home/user/data_dir/*.nc')

mean_list = []
for filename in filename_list:  # make filename_list with something like os.listdir
    with netCDF4.Dataset(filename) as ds:
        mean_list.append(np.mean(ds.variables['pbl'][:, 0]))
```

To do the same thing with `xarray`:

```
import xarray as xr
from glob import glob

# you want to modify this to use your actual data directory
filename_list = glob('/home/user/data_dir/*.nc')

mean_list = []
for filename in filename_list:  # make filename_list with something like os.listdir
    with xr.open_dataset(filename) as ds:
        mean_list.append(np.mean(ds['pbl'][:, 0].values))
```

If instead of getting the average for each file, let's say the first dimension is `time` and you want to get the average among *all* the files. To do that with `xarray`, you could use `open_mfdataset` like so:

```
import xarray as xr
import os
from glob import glob

# you want to modify this to use your actual data directory
filename_list = glob('/home/user/data_dir/*.nc')

ds = xr.open_mfdataset(filename_list, concat_dim='time')
mean = np.mean(ds['pbl'][:, 0].values)
```

Comment: woooww it worked. thank you so much Jeremy. Thanks a lot .